# What's the difference between these ways of finishing an Activity with setResult?

Tags: android, android-activity

1.

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
finish();
```

2.

```
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
finish();
```

3.

```
setResult(RESULT_OK, getIntent());
finish();
```

I have seen them all the time, but I'm not sure if they all do exactly the same or not.

Comment: Um, #3 is probably a bug. Leastways, I cannot think of any standard Android `Intent` action, for which the output is supposed to be the same `Intent` as the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1 + 3:** finishes the current activity & sends back an intent (data) to the caller activity.

**2:** finishes the current activity.

*(In all cases, it sets the result as `RESULT_OK`, which you can check against the `resultCode` argument of the `onActivityResult()` method, defined in the caller activity)*

Comment: For 1+3, in what scenarios you do getIntent() or new Intent() ?

Comment: If you want to **send data back** to the activity that summoned this one.

Comment: But is there a difference between them?

Comment: `getIntent()` comes with the activity itself. In general, when you want to send data back to an activity, you better create a new intent.